# Can't seem to get Node js and NPM up and running: Reference Error on every command

Tags: node.js, npm

I just installed node-v4.4.5-x64 and I'm using Windows 10 but everything I type into the command line (even -h and --help) gives me a ReferenceError: h is not defined. I'm just getting started trying to use NPM so i'm pretty new to this. What am I doing wrong? How can I get started with NPM?

Comment: Can you access node itself . may be npm is not in your env variable

Comment: I'm running /nodejs/node.exe

Comment: add the path of your path of nodejs folder to your env variable . Once you have done you can access the npm module from then onwards

Comment: How do I go about doing that? Sorry this is all new to me...

Comment: In your command prompt

`set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\nodejs`
I f your using nix env

`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/nodejs/`

Comment: Do you mean windows command prompt? node.exe? or nmp.cmd? Actually I tried all 3 and I'm still at a loss...

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Visual Studio 2017 run `npm` from `Package Manager Console`, not `Node.js Interactive Window`

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you're running the `npm` commands from within the node REPL: `/nodejs/node.exe` starts the node REPL. The reason the error is a `ReferenceError` is because the variable `npm` is not defined within the REPL.

What you want to do is run the commands inside the terminal. You'll need to exit the node REPL by pressing `Ctrl + D`. You should be in the terminal now.

Comment: That didn't work, pressing ctrl + d didn't really do anything. Is there a way to access the terminal directly?

Comment: Hi David, did you ever figure out how to access the terminal directly? Ctrl-D did not work for me either.